# Java - Spring(HSql + Rest) - date time format in the POST vs HSQL database

Tags: java

I am trying to build a very minimalistic `rest` application in `spring` with `HSQL` in memory database.

I have a `date` column in one entity. I am able to `POST` messages through the rest endpoint and fill in the database. I can also `GET` messages. When I try to `GET` messages using a search `findByDate` I am not getting any results back.

If I do a `GET localhost:8080/weather` to the web server endpoint, I get the following output

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "weather": [
            {
                "city": "Amsterdam",
                "date": "2019-01-30T00:00:00.000+0000",
                "unit": "celcius",
                "lowTemp": "-5",
                "highTemp": "3",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/weather/1"
                    },
                    "weather": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/weather/1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/weather{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/weather"
        },
        "search": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/weather/search"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 1,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

But when I go a `GET localhost:8080/weather/search/findByDate?date=2019-01-30T00:00:00.000+0000` I get unparsable date error.

I tried many different date time formats in my GET request. Nothing worked.

```
2019-01-30T00:00:00.000+0000
2019-01-30'T'00:00:00.000+0000
```

Can someone help me with the right format to use?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime
.parse(
    "2019-01-30T00:00:00.000+0000".replace( "+0000" , "+00:00" )
)
```

…and…

```
OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toString()
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/JgDPVK).

> 2019-01-27T02:11:42.754Z

The `Z` on the end means UTC, as a shortcut for `+00:00`. Commonly used in date-time work. Specified in the ISO 8601 standard. Pronounced “Zulu”.

## details

Your Question does not provide enough detail for a definitive solution. But this might get you headed in the right direction.

The time-of-day in your date-time happens to be 00:00. So I suspect you want a date-only value rather than a moment (without time-of-day and without time zone or offset-from-UTC). If so, use `LocalDate` object in Java, and use standard ISO 8601 format in text of the format YYYY-MM-DD.

```
ZoneID z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

You can parse such a string. The *java.time* classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default, so no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-30" ) ;
```

If you want to parse a moment in the format of your example, parse as a `OffsetDateTime`. Unfortunately, your input omitted the optional colon character in the offset, and the `OffsetDateTime` class has a small bug in parsing without the colon. So do a search-and-replace to make `+0000` into `00:00`.

```
String input = 2019-01-30T00:00:00.000+0000".replace( "+0000" , "+00:00" ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```